# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, illegalstateexception

I am getting below exception while retrieving data from SQLLite database.

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it
```

on line  `String username= result.getString(1);`

MainActivity

```
mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase myDatabase=openOrCreateDatabase("Login",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Login(Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
                myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO Login VALUES('"+mUserName.getText()+"','"+mPassword.getText()+"');");

            }
        });
```

SecondActivity

```
  SQLiteDatabase myDatabase=openOrCreateDatabase("Login",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

                Cursor result=myDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from Login",null);
             result.moveToFirst();
                String username= result.getString(1);
                String password=result.getString(2);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try adding if(result.moveToFirst()) then get username and password. and column index starts from 0

Comment: @Raghunandan still same exception

Comment: did you change the column index to 0 and 1. It says there is no column 2

Comment: @Raghunandan yeah i changed..i hope i don't need to add any permission in manifest

Comment: you still get that the same exception  Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow??

Comment: @Raghunandan yeah..same exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103872/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user3684678).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
 String username= result.getString(0);
 String password=result.getString(1);
```

Cursor index starts from zero

Full code

```
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase=openOrCreateDatabase("Login",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
Cursor result=myDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from Login",null);
if (result.moveToFirst()) {      
   String username= result.getString(0);
   String password=result.getString(1);                
}
```

Comment: same exception i am getting wid this also

Comment: I think it should work. Uninstall your app and install a fresh copy again